# How to open react project in browser using WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a react project from a webstorm, I just don't know how to open it in a browser. Could anyone have given directions on how to open the project in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you open your terminal in the program and run `npm start`.

Alternatively, you can configure it to run when you press the play button in the toolbar. You can read how to do that [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html#react_running_and_debugging_run).